# TV no longer showing up on cec-client scan

Tags: pi-3, chromium, cec-client

I am using a Raspberry Pi model 3 as a simple signage display (web page through Chromium in kiosk mode) and have used cec-utils to manage on/off times for the TV. I have had this same setup for about 5 months now. Until recently, it has worked perfectly but as of two weeks ago, the RPi can no longer turn on/off the TV via cec-utils and it won't show up as a device when I do a scan. Here is the results of a cec scan for the TV:

```bsh
    echo "scan" | cec-client -s
    opening a connection to the CEC adapter...
    DEBUG:   [             164] Broadcast (F): osd name set to 'Broadcast'
    DEBUG:   [             164] Open - vc_cec initialised
    DEBUG:   [             164] logical address changed to Free use (e)
    NOTICE:  [             164] connection opened
    DEBUG:   [             165] processor thread started
    DEBUG:   [             165] << Broadcast (F) -> TV (0): POLL
    DEBUG:   [             165] initiator 'Broadcast' is not supported by the CEC adapter. using 'Free use' instead
    TRAFFIC: [             165] << e0
    DEBUG:   [            1165] command 'feature abort' timeout
    DEBUG:   [            1665] initiator 'Broadcast' is not supported by the CEC adapter. using 'Free use' instead
    TRAFFIC: [            1666] << e0
    DEBUG:   [            1696] >> POLL not sent
    DEBUG:   [            1696] TV (0): device status changed into 'not present'
    NOTICE:  [            1696] registering new CEC client - v4.0.4
    DEBUG:   [            1696] detecting logical address for type 'recording device'
    DEBUG:   [            1696] trying logical address 'Recorder 1'
    DEBUG:   [            1696] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Recorder 1 (1): POLL
    TRAFFIC: [            1696] << 11
    TRAFFIC: [            3228] << 11
    DEBUG:   [            4759] >> POLL not sent
    DEBUG:   [            4759] using logical address 'Recorder 1'
    DEBUG:   [            4759] Recorder 1 (1): device status changed into 'handled by libCEC'
    DEBUG:   [            4759] Recorder 1 (1): power status changed from 'unknown' to 'on'
    DEBUG:   [            4759] Recorder 1 (1): vendor = Pulse Eight (001582)
    DEBUG:   [            4759] Recorder 1 (1): CEC version 1.4
    DEBUG:   [            4759] AllocateLogicalAddresses - device '0', type 'recording device', LA '1'
    WARNING: [            4759] RegisterLogicalAddress - vc_cec_set_logical_address(1) returned device is busy (3)
    DEBUG:   [            4759] UnregisterLogicalAddress - releasing previous logical address
    DEBUG:   [            4759] logical address changed to Broadcast (f)
    DEBUG:   [            4759] Recorder 1 (1): osd name set to 'CECTester'
    DEBUG:   [            4759] Recorder 1 (1): menu language set to 'eng'
    DEBUG:   [            4760] GetPhysicalAddress - physical address = 2000
    DEBUG:   [            4760] AutodetectPhysicalAddress - autodetected physical address '2000'
    DEBUG:   [            4760] Recorder 1 (1): physical address changed from ffff to 2000
    DEBUG:   [            4760] << Recorder 1 (1) -> broadcast (F): physical address 2000
    TRAFFIC: [            4760] << 1f:84:20:00:01
    DEBUG:   [            4760] sending command 'report physical address' failed (4)
    TRAFFIC: [            4760] << 1f:84:20:00:01
    DEBUG:   [            4761] sending command 'report physical address' failed (4)
    NOTICE:  [            4761] CEC client registered: libCEC version = 4.0.4, client version = 4.0.4, firmware version = 1, logical address(es) = Recorder 1 (1) , physical address: 2.0.0.0, git revision: libcec-4.0.4, compiled on Fri Feb  1 01:48:47 UTC 2019 by root@hostname: Name or service not known on Linux 4.15.0-44-generic (armv7l), features: P8_USB, DRM, P8_detect, randr, RPi
    DEBUG:   [            4761] << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): OSD name 'CECTester'
    DEBUG:   [            4761] << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): POLL
    TRAFFIC: [            4761] << 10
    DEBUG:   [            4761] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    TRAFFIC: [            4761] << 10
    DEBUG:   [            4761] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    DEBUG:   [            4761] >> POLL not sent
    DEBUG:   [            4761] not sending command 'set osd name': destination device 'TV' marked as not present
    DEBUG:   [            4761] << requesting power status of 'TV' (0)
    DEBUG:   [            4761] << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): POLL
    TRAFFIC: [            4761] << 10
    DEBUG:   [            4762] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    TRAFFIC: [            4762] << 10
    DEBUG:   [            4762] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    DEBUG:   [            4762] >> POLL not sent
    DEBUG:   [            4762] not sending command 'give device power status': destination device 'TV' marked as not present
    requesting CEC bus information ...
    DEBUG:   [            4762] << Recorder 1 (1) -> TV (0): POLL
    TRAFFIC: [            4762] << 10
    DEBUG:   [            4762] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    TRAFFIC: [            4762] << 10
    DEBUG:   [            4762] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    DEBUG:   [            4762] >> POLL not sent
    DEBUG:   [            4762] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Recorder 2 (2): POLL
    TRAFFIC: [            4763] << 12
    DEBUG:   [            4763] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    TRAFFIC: [            4763] << 12
    DEBUG:   [            4763] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    DEBUG:   [            4763] >> POLL not sent
    DEBUG:   [            4763] Recorder 2 (2): device status changed into 'not present'
    DEBUG:   [            4763] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Tuner 1 (3): POLL
    TRAFFIC: [            4763] << 13
    DEBUG:   [            4763] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    TRAFFIC: [            4763] << 13
    DEBUG:   [            4763] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    DEBUG:   [            4763] >> POLL not sent
    DEBUG:   [            4763] Tuner 1 (3): device status changed into 'not present'
    DEBUG:   [            4763] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Playback 1 (4): POLL
    TRAFFIC: [            4764] << 14
    DEBUG:   [            4764] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    TRAFFIC: [            4764] << 14
    DEBUG:   [            4764] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    DEBUG:   [            4764] >> POLL not sent
    DEBUG:   [            4764] Playback 1 (4): device status changed into 'not present'
    DEBUG:   [            4764] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Audio (5): POLL
    TRAFFIC: [            4764] << 15
    DEBUG:   [            4764] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    TRAFFIC: [            4764] << 15
    DEBUG:   [            4764] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    DEBUG:   [            4764] >> POLL not sent
    DEBUG:   [            4764] Audio (5): device status changed into 'not present'
    DEBUG:   [            4764] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Tuner 2 (6): POLL
    TRAFFIC: [            4764] << 16
    DEBUG:   [            4765] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    TRAFFIC: [            4765] << 16
    DEBUG:   [            4765] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    DEBUG:   [            4765] >> POLL not sent
    DEBUG:   [            4765] Tuner 2 (6): device status changed into 'not present'
    DEBUG:   [            4765] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Tuner 3 (7): POLL
    TRAFFIC: [            4765] << 17
    DEBUG:   [            4765] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    TRAFFIC: [            4765] << 17
    DEBUG:   [            4765] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    DEBUG:   [            4765] >> POLL not sent
    DEBUG:   [            4765] Tuner 3 (7): device status changed into 'not present'
    DEBUG:   [            4765] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Playback 2 (8): POLL
    TRAFFIC: [            4765] << 18
    DEBUG:   [            4766] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    TRAFFIC: [            4766] << 18
    DEBUG:   [            4766] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    DEBUG:   [            4766] >> POLL not sent
    DEBUG:   [            4766] Playback 2 (8): device status changed into 'not present'
    DEBUG:   [            4766] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Recorder 3 (9): POLL
    TRAFFIC: [            4766] << 19
    DEBUG:   [            4766] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    TRAFFIC: [            4766] << 19
    DEBUG:   [            4766] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    DEBUG:   [            4766] >> POLL not sent
    DEBUG:   [            4766] Recorder 3 (9): device status changed into 'not present'
    DEBUG:   [            4766] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Tuner 4 (A): POLL
    TRAFFIC: [            4767] << 1a
    DEBUG:   [            4767] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    TRAFFIC: [            4767] << 1a
    DEBUG:   [            4767] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    DEBUG:   [            4767] >> POLL not sent
    DEBUG:   [            4767] Tuner 4 (A): device status changed into 'not present'
    DEBUG:   [            4767] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Playback 3 (B): POLL
    TRAFFIC: [            4767] << 1b
    DEBUG:   [            4767] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    TRAFFIC: [            4767] << 1b
    DEBUG:   [            4768] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    DEBUG:   [            4768] >> POLL not sent
    DEBUG:   [            4768] Playback 3 (B): device status changed into 'not present'
    DEBUG:   [            4768] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Reserved 1 (C): POLL
    TRAFFIC: [            4768] << 1c
    DEBUG:   [            4768] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    TRAFFIC: [            4768] << 1c
    DEBUG:   [            4768] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    DEBUG:   [            4768] >> POLL not sent
    DEBUG:   [            4768] Reserved 1 (C): device status changed into 'not present'
    DEBUG:   [            4768] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Reserved 2 (D): POLL
    TRAFFIC: [            4768] << 1d
    DEBUG:   [            4768] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    TRAFFIC: [            4768] << 1d
    DEBUG:   [            4768] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    DEBUG:   [            4769] >> POLL not sent
    DEBUG:   [            4769] Reserved 2 (D): device status changed into 'not present'
    DEBUG:   [            4769] << Recorder 1 (1) -> Free use (E): POLL
    TRAFFIC: [            4769] << 1e
    DEBUG:   [            4769] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    TRAFFIC: [            4769] << 1e
    DEBUG:   [            4769] sending command 'feature abort' failed (4)
    DEBUG:   [            4769] >> POLL not sent
    DEBUG:   [            4769] Free use (E): device status changed into 'not present'
    DEBUG:   [            4769] << requesting active source
    TRAFFIC: [            4769] << 1f:85
    DEBUG:   [            4769] sending command 'request active source' failed (4)
    TRAFFIC: [            4769] << 1f:85
    DEBUG:   [            4770] sending command 'request active source' failed (4)
    DEBUG:   [            4770] << requesting active source
    TRAFFIC: [            4770] << 1f:85
    DEBUG:   [            4770] sending command 'request active source' failed (4)
    TRAFFIC: [            4770] << 1f:85
    CEC bus information
    ===================
    device #1: Recorder 1
    address:       2.0.0.0
    active source: no
    vendor:        Pulse Eight
    osd string:    CECTester
    CEC version:   1.4
    power status:  on
    language:      eng


    currently active source: unknown (-1)
    DEBUG:   [            4770] sending command 'request active source' failed (4)
    DEBUG:   [            4771] unregistering all CEC clients
    NOTICE:  [            4771] unregistering client: libCEC version = 4.0.4, client version = 4.0.4, firmware version = 1, logical address(es) = Recorder 1 (1) , physical address: 2.0.0.0, git revision: libcec-4.0.4, compiled on Fri Feb  1 01:48:47 UTC 2019 by root@hostname: Name or service not known on Linux 4.15.0-44-generic (armv7l), features: P8_USB, DRM, P8_detect, randr, RPi
    DEBUG:   [            4771] Recorder 1 (1): power status changed from 'on' to 'unknown'
    DEBUG:   [            4771] Recorder 1 (1): vendor = Unknown (000000)
    DEBUG:   [            4771] Recorder 1 (1): CEC version unknown
    DEBUG:   [            4771] Recorder 1 (1): osd name set to 'Recorder 1'
    DEBUG:   [            4771] Recorder 1 (1): device status changed into 'unknown'
    DEBUG:   [            4771] unregistering all CEC clients
    DEBUG:   [            5166] UnregisterLogicalAddress - releasing previous logical address
    DEBUG:   [            5166] logical address changed to Broadcast (f)
```

The only recent change that I can think of that could even possibly have affected this was when I made a script to allow a non-admin user to refresh the web-page via ssh using xdotools. It involved changing the DISPLAY so that's why I'm thinking maybe that had something to do with it but I'm not sure. Here is that script:

```bsh
    #!/bin/bash
    DISPLAY=:0.0
    export DISPLAY
    WID=$(xdotool search --onlyvisible --class chromium|head -1)
    xdotool windowactivate ${WID}
    xdotool key ctrl+F5
```

Comment: Best bet would be to revert the changes you made and see if you can get it back to original working order, then re-implement the changes one at a time until you figure out what broke it.

Comment: I reset the DISPLAY variable using DISPLAY="" and that hasn't solved the problem. The other parts of the posted script are simply using xdotool to refresh a web page so it makes no changes to the display

Answer (score 3):

Okay, after resetting the TV to factory settings, completely reinstalling Raspbian/cec-utils, and putting a new HDMI cable in the mix, the solution ended up being embarrassingly easy: unplugging and plugging back in the TV. I didn't do that before because the power was really hard to get to and I thought a factory reset would accomplish the same thing :/

Lesson here, kids, is to always unplug and replug your problems *before* spending hours on more complicated "fixes."

Comment: Please don't mark the title with [Solved]. We do not use that. Instead accept your answer after two days. That's the right way to finish a question.